# Does the entire universe contain photons?

Tags: visible-light, space

Since light travels in all directions, and since there is an infinite source of light in the universe, wouldn't that mean that ALL space within the universe must be filled with photons? (and that there really isn't any possibility that "places" exist where light (photons) are absent?)

Comment: What do you mean when you say, "there is an infinite source of light in the universe?"  Are you asking about the Cosmic Microwave Background?  Or maybe what I'm asking is, What do you mean by a "universe...filled with photons?"  Would you expect that to be different from the universe that we actually live in? and if so, how?

Comment: Obligatory [Olbers paradox search](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=olbers+paradox)

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be related to [Olber's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olbers%27_paradox), i.e., why is the sky mostly dark when the universe is infinite and eternal and there must come light from infinitely many stars existing in any given direction. The modern resolution of this paradox relies on the fact that the universe is expanding since the big bang and that the light of all stars, which is red-shifted the further away they are,  has not yet reached us or will never reach us beyond a certain distance (cosmic light horizon).